# Unable to see Ruby on Rails App deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have successfully deployed Ruby on Rails app on Heroku. But when I visit the URL given by Heroku, error says: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

URL - https://cryptic-waters-2558.herokuapp.com/

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is up and running, since the error message comes from `Webrick`. Probable cause of this error is lack of some initial data (maybe you forgot to run `heroku run rake db:seed`), which causes `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error. You can check this easily with `heroku logs` or `heroku logs -t`, which works similar to `tail -f`.

Comment: @Yogesh did my answer provide any help?

Comment: I run "heroku run rake db:seed" still can't see my app. I have created a GIST file of Heroku Logs, please see what's wrong

Comment: @Yogesh can you give link or sth?

Comment: @Yogesh what are your routes?

Comment: `code` Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create]
  end

  resources :posts end `code`

Comment: @Yogesh you should update question with this data. And how do you expect it to work since you don't have route to `/`? Did you learn something about Ruby on Rails before trying to create an application? And BTW, when I go to `/posts`, I get 500 error, so there's something wrong with your whole app, probably (or, maybe, you forgot to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`), so get to logs and try to debug it.

Comment: App is working fine on http://localhost:3000 I followed this guide strictly to create this app( http://railsinstallfest.org/guides/installfest41/getting_started/ ) and everything running via "rails server"

Comment: @Yogesh and what page do you have when you go to `localhost:3000/`?

Comment: @Yogesh What you mean by this? You get redirected to `localhost:3000/posts` when you go to `localhost:3000`?

Comment: It is working @Marek you're awesome. I am visiting this URL https://cryptic-waters-2558.herokuapp.com/posts/ working fine. how can I run my app on this URL only: https://cryptic-waters-2558.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @Yogesh add proper route to `routes.rb`, I won't lead you by the hand. And accept my answer, if you found it helpful. :)

Comment: @Yogesh, read the first comment from Guest in the tutorial you followed, which shows it was posted 7 days ago.

Comment: How do I accept your answer as helpful? I mean where to click?