# Rails tutorial mhhartl toy_app successful deployment on heroku, unable to retrieve page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I hope life's great and you're busy coding.

I am following mhartl's Rails tutorial for I am really eager to learn RoR for web app development. I tried to troubleshoot by starting from scratch several times which had me going through the pain of creating new bitbucket repos and so on. Anyways I felt you guys probably faced this already so you might be able to help.

After all the steps in the tutorial, up to 2.1, which is

```
$ git commit -am "Add hello"
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

and seems to be successful given the shell message below:

```
remote:        https://fast-sea-56609.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/fast-sea-56609.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

when I go to the URL, I get this screenshot with the message
[The page you were looking for doesn't exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbjXV.png)

I checked this post [Unable to see Ruby on Rails App deployed on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269453/unable-to-see-ruby-on-rails-app-deployed-on-heroku) and I solved the localhost:3000 db migration thingy so now I have localhost:3000/users displaying properly but the heroku url does not display any different.

Tell me if I can provide more informations or run anything to help you troubleshoot. Thanks for the time you spent on reading this rather than doing anything else.

Comment: please post your heroku log files with question to see the errors in heroku

Comment: Hey Praveen, thanks for your comment, I'm not sure how to get that is it the heroku logs command?

Comment: to get heroku logs just run $ heroku logs   in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are following [Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org) I suggest you to complete each task or chapter till the end.

Here the problem caused might be because you missed a part of your tutorial, that the autor ask you to complete the first applications step again with your toy application like bellow:

**I suggest doing by following the same “hello, world!” steps in Listing 1.8 and Listing 1.9.1(Did you do these steps in your application before committing and pushing to heroku ?) Then commit the changes and push up to Heroku:**

```
$ git commit -am "Add hello"
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

Once you finish making the first working copy of you Rails app in local the next step is to deploy it in heroku to test your app in production environment.

Yo can follow the official Heroku guide to know more about [deploying an application into heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)
 from this link.

Comment: It works now thank you big time I was obsessed with git and heroku and it was all there in front of my eyes. Cheers Prav.

Comment: @keithshelby : if my answer was helpful in solving your problem please accept my answer ( click on the tick mark on my answer ).

Comment: sorry I +1 it but did not know about the tick mark. Done :) !

Answer (score 0):

You said you ran rake db:migrate on your local machine. But did you run it on heroku as well?

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Remember you need to call this command each time you add new migration to your rails project and push the changes to heroku.

Be sure to check heroku logs for other errors:

```
heroku logs
```

Comment: Thanks miloshes, indeed I forgot to run the migration on heroku. I ran it now. The app is still not up on the heroku url. The log is not showing any error. Any what can be done next?

Comment: Run heroku logs with tail parameter:
    heroku logs --tail
and refresh the url several times.
It could just need a restart. The command is:
    heroku restart

Comment: hey miloshes, I ran the heroku logs --tail and also restarted... none worked out thanks anyways. I'll try to follow Praveen's link and figure out if it works